# Trying to compare strings into regular expressions patterns

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I compare a regex pattern into a String?

Example: "Street A 2 b"

for this case I use:

```
re.split("([0-9]+)", address)
```

However, for another case "Street 23" I use

```
re.split("([0-9]+)", address)
```

I need to build this like the two cases in a way that they can talk to each other.
If I input "Street A 2 b" I need the output ['Street A', '2 b']
If I input "Street 23" I need the output ['Street', '23']

I tried to do:

```
address = str(input('Enter the address: '))

if address != re.search(r"([0-9]+ [a-z]+)", address):
    my_list = re.split("([0-9]+)", address)
    print(my_list)
else:
    my_list = re.split("([0-9]+ [a-z]+)", address)
    print(my_list)
```

But it's not working

I need the program identify each of the two cases and output correctly.

---

Comment: `re.search` doesn't return a string, so `address` will never be equal to that. In your own words, can you describe the logic to decide where to split? How do you know that you need to split `"Street A 2 b"` at the _second_ space, and not the first or third? Is this always the case when there are more than one space?

Comment: I think you mean `if re.search(...):`. `re.search()` returns a truthy value if it successfully matched the regexp, otherwise it returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want using a lookahead in the pattern. This will use a space that's followed by a number as the delimiter.

```
def split_address(address):
    return re.split(r'\s+(?=\d)', address)

print(split_address('Street A 2 b'))
print(split_address('Street 23'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split on the first whitespace+number, but only once with `maxsplit=1`. <strike>but this leaves you with 3 element list, so you have to join the end back together. Not sure if it is possible to do it without the joining.</strike> E: Stole the lookahead pattern from Barmar's answer.

```
import re

address = input('Enter the address: ')

my_list = re.split(" (?=[0-9])", address, maxsplit=1)
print(my_list)
```

FYI: `input` should already return a `str` so no need to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex features:

```py
import re

match = re.match(r"(\D+)(.*)", "Street A 2 b")

print("'%s', '%s'" % (match[1].strip(), match[2].strip()))
```

### Output

'Street A', '2 b'

### Notes

Pattern `\D+` searches for all successive non-digit characters. The matching pattern uses grouping (using parentheses). So the first part (street) is stored in `match[1]`, and the remaining part (number...) in `match[2]`.
To remove unwanted spaces `strip()` is used.